# Zend Route with subdomain yahoo like

Tags: zend-framework, router, hostname

I would like to use Zend Route to treat URI like, http:/US.video.yahoo.com and also http://video.yahoo.com with the same route. For the second proposition i would like that the system tell me that the country that was to "US" in the first one, is now at NULL.

But i don't arrive to have Zend Route Hostname doing regex like stuffs.

How could i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve routing on the hostname you need Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname

```
$hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':country.:controller.yahoo.com',
    array( 'action' => 'index' )
);
```

To combine your hostname route to other routes you need Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain

```
$staticRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('');

$router->addRoute('default', $hostnameRoute->chain($staticRoute));
```

Check out the Zend framework manual, there are some good examples for you to follow.